# adjust height of element in css

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```css
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
   
    background-size: 100px 30px;
    background-repeaT: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 30px, center center, center 140px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test one"></div>
```

I found the pen online, and want to adjust it for my own usage, however, cannot figure out a few things.

I want to move the blue box lower, so it is not as high, but still keep the same shape. So I tried background position, as one would, and it doesn't change anything. I'm relatively an amateur in css so it is probably a silly question, but a question none the less! Appreciate the help

Comment: Justinas is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because that shape is made with linear gradient as background, so you just need to adjust gradient percentages:

From

`background: linear-gradient(25deg, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);`

to

`background: linear-gradient(25deg, yellow 20%, transparent 20%);`

```css
.test {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: white;
    display: inline-block;
   
    background-size: 100px 30px;
    background-repeaT: no-repeat;
    background-position: center 30px, center center, center 140px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.test:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, yellow 20%, transparent 20%);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="test one"></div>
```